# Jenkins: deploying war files from artifactory

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

We are using **Jenkins** to build (**maven**) & deploy artifacts (JARs & **WAR**s) to an in-house artifactory server (both snapshots and releases).

For deployment, currently, we got Jenkins jobs that package the war file (from a release scm tag) and deploy to different environments/servers. We want to skip the package phase as it seems unnecessary to package it again & again for a released version because it's not possible to get a different copy of war file even after trying 1000 times.

We are looking for a way in Jenkins to get the artifact (war) from Artifactory and deploy it to a container. I am sure other people would have faced this situation too but I am not able to find any online material regarding this.

**Is there any Jenkins plugin that takes a war file from Artifactory (based on a version) and deploy it to a remote container?**

**If this is not the right way of doing it then what are the recommendations for any other approach?**

Thanks

Comment: found something useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7785290/1844874, will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a plugin which takes a version # and deploys that, but you can build a Jenkins job to deploy the last successful release to a previous environment (thus copying from DEV-->QA for example.)

To do this, you would use the copy-artifact-plugin.

Here's an easy to follow run-through of this kind of setup:

http://www.lordofthejars.com/2012/09/deploying-jee-artifacts-with-jenkins.html

Answer (score 1):

Every artifact stored in Artifactory will have a unique URL that includes the version number.  It will take the format

```
http://artifactory-server/repository-name/path-to-artifact/version/filename
```

e.g.

```
http://artifactory/apps-releases-local/com/yourorg/yourapp/1.5.67/webapp.war
```

(depending on how you do your packaging, the WAR file name may include the version number as well).

So your deployment job can construct the Artifactory URL and download the file. Depending on how you have security set up in Artifactory, you may need to authenticate the request.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. My question here is how do I make a deployment job in jenkins that download the war file from a URL?

Comment: You don't say what web container you're using; Maven has a built in Tomcat deployment, see http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/  Otherwise you can just write a shell build step in Jenkins to do the deployment steps.

Comment: I am using Tomcat. Does maven-tomcat-plugin allow deploying a war that is stored on artifactory? Writing a shell script to download the war and deploy makes sense but I was just wondering if this is been already done in some jenkins or maven plugin that I am not aware of.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the Maven plugin, but I think it will take the locally produced WAR file and deploy it from the build slave.  You could still publish the WAR to Artifactory in a separate step if you want to, you just don't need to deploy it from Artifactory.