# How to deploy shadow jar with jenkins artifactory plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle, publish, artifactory

I'm using com.github.johnrengelman.shadow plugin in gradle to be able to create shadow jar.
How can i deploy this jar (and not the main artifact) from jenkins artifactory plugin?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869402/jenkins-deploying-war-files-from-artifactory) and [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management)

Comment: @DominikGebhart Currently i'm looking to deploy snapshot version only. Two artifacts created after build - one is named <project>-<version>.jar and another one is <project>-<version>-all.jar (from shadowJar gradle plugin). I want to deploy the second one, while jenkins artifactory plugin deploys the first one. Any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131814/how-to-script-gradle-in-order-to-publish-shadowjar-into-artifactory) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155345/how-to-change-the-jar-filename-when-upload-to-artifactory-via-gradle) deals with a similar issue, maybe it helps and you can avoid the dirty fix.

Comment: Actually i need only the artifact created from shadowjar task. Anyway, tried suggested but it didn't work, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by renaming artifact created by shadowJar task to the project-version.jar name and overwriting original jar